# Issue with Spring Security MethodSecurityEvaluationContext lookupVariable and addArgumentsAsVariables methods

Tags: spring-security, aop

I have an issue with `MethodSecurityEvaluationContext` `lookupVariable` and `addArgumentsAsVariables` methods which is as follows:

The `paramNames` local variable itself **is not null** but **always contains a null entry**.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

[image: screen capture]

Here is the method annotated with `@PreAuthorize` (in a Roo-generated itd):

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() AND hasPermission(#id, 'CurriculumService:findCurriculumIsAllowed')")
public Curriculum CurriculumServiceImpl.findCurriculum(Long id) {
    return curriculumRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given the answer to the above question. One has to annotate the parameter with `@P("id")` as shown below:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() AND hasPermission(#id, 'CurriculumService:findCurriculumIsAllowed')")
public Curriculum CurriculumServiceImpl.findCurriculum(@P("id") Long id) {
    return curriculumRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

[See documentation here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize)